# php forgot password page

Tags: php, passwords, reset

I got this code from a website and I have been altering it to fit my needs. The problem that I am facing is that the password reset page is not firing a new password off by php mail but instead it is refreshing the page and the user is stuck on a php include file and not the site.

I know some php but this seems to be beyond me. After 12+hrs of trying different things I am asking for help :)

I hope its an easy fix. Thanks in advance for your help and code snippets.

```
<?php 
include 'dbc.php';
/******************* ACTIVATION BY FORM**************************/
if ($_POST['doReset']=='Reset')
{
$err = array();
$msg = array();

foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $data[$key] = filter($value);
}
if(!isEmail($data['user_email'])) {
$err[] = "ERROR - Please enter a valid email"; 
    header("Location: index.html?p=unknownuser");
}

$user_email = $data['user_email'];

//check if activ code and user is valid as precaution
$rs_check = mysql_query("select id from users where user_email='$user_email'") or die (mysql_error()); 
$num = mysql_num_rows($rs_check);
  // Match row found with more than 1 results  - the user is authenticated. 
    if ( $num <= 0 ) { 
    $err[] = "Error - Sorry no such account exists or registered.";
    header("Location: index.html?p=unknownuser");
    //exit();
    }


if(empty($err)) {

$new_pwd = GenPwd();
$pwd_reset = PwdHash($new_pwd);
//$sha1_new = sha1($new);   
//set update sha1 of new password + salt
$rs_activ = mysql_query("update users set pwd='$pwd_reset' WHERE 
                         user_email='$user_email'") or die(mysql_error());

$host  = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$host_upper = strtoupper($host);                         

//send email

$message = 
"Here are your new password details ...\n
User Email: $user_email \n
Passwd: $new_pwd \n

Thank You

Administrator
$host_upper
______________________________________________________
THIS IS AN AUTOMATED RESPONSE. 
***DO NOT RESPOND TO THIS EMAIL****
";

    mail($user_email, "Reset Password", $message,
    "From: \"Client Password Reset\" <clientservices@example.com>\r\n" .
     "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());

  header("Location: index.html?p=newpassword");  
  exit();

     } 
 }  


/*
    mail($user_email, "Reset Password", $message,
    "From: \"Client Registration\" <clientservices@example.com>\r\n" .
     "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion());                       

$msg[] = "Your account password has been reset and a new password has been sent to your email address.";                        
//header("Location: index.html?p=newpassword");                      
//$msg = urlencode();
//header("Location: forgot.php?msg=$msg");                       
//exit();
 }
}
 */
?>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="jquery/jquery.validate.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#actForm").validate();
  });
  </script>
        <?php
      /******************** ERROR MESSAGES*************************************************
      This code is to show error messages 
      **************************************************************************/
    if(!empty($err))  {
       echo "<div class=\"msg\">";
      foreach ($err as $e) {
        echo "* $e <br>";
        }
      echo "</div>";    
       }
       if(!empty($msg))  {
        echo "<div class=\"msg\">" . $msg[0] . "</div>";

       }
      /******************************* END ********************************/      
      ?><div id="clientLogin">You are about to request a reset of your client account password | <a href="?p=login" class="clientLogin">Login</a><br>
      <form action="forgot.php" method="post" name="actForm" id="actForm" style="margin-top:5px;">
       Your Email <input name="user_email" type="text" class="required email" id="txtboxn" size="25"><input name="doReset" type="submit" id="doLogin3" value="Submit" class="button"></form></div>
```

Comment: Where are the GenPwd and PwdHash functions?

Comment: `function checkPwd($x,$y) 
{
if(empty($x) || empty($y) ) { return false; }
if (strlen($x) < 4 || strlen($y) < 4) { return false; }

if (strcmp($x,$y) != 0) {
 return false;
 } 
return true;
}`

Comment: `function GenPwd($length = 7)
{
  $password = "";
  $possible = "0123456789bcdfghjkmnpqrstvwxyz"; //no vowels
  
  $i = 0; 
    
  while ($i < $length) { 

    
    $char = substr($possible, mt_rand(0, strlen($possible)-1), 1);
       
    
    if (!strstr($password, $char)) { 
      $password .= $char;
      $i++;
    }

  }

  return $password;

}`

Comment: `// Password and salt generation
function PwdHash($pwd, $salt = null)
{
    if ($salt === null)     {
        $salt = substr(md5(uniqid(rand(), true)), 0, SALT_LENGTH);
    }
    else     {
        $salt = substr($salt, 0, SALT_LENGTH);
    }
    return $salt . sha1($pwd . $salt);
}

function checkAdmin() {

if($_SESSION['user_level'] == ADMIN_LEVEL) {
return 1;
} else { return 0 ;
}

}`

Comment: they are in the file called dbc.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have:

```
mail($usr_email, "Reset Password", $message...);
```

When it looks like you should have

```
mail($user_email, "Reset Password", $message...);
```

Notice you used `$usr_email` instead of `$user_email`.

That is why no email is being sent.  Then it looks like the user is redirected to `index.html?p=newpassword` so depending on what that page is it may appear to just be reloading the same page.

UPDATE:

Also, you have the element `doReset` with a value of `Submit` and in your PHP code you are checking to see that `$_POST['doReset']` == `Reset` instead of `Submit`.

```
<input name="doReset" type="submit" id="doLogin3" value="Submit" class="button">
```

Change
    `if ($_POST['doReset']=='Reset')`
to
    `if ($_POST['doReset']=='Submit')`

Comment: even with the edit it is still refreshing the page on submit to show just the include file and not taking the user to index.html?p=newpassword

Comment: Thanks, and good luck.  You may want to look into a PHP editor like Eclipse with PDT because it will point out simple mistakes like the `$usr_email` issue.  Not so much with the second one, but a good php editor is very helpful in development.

Comment: I will look into it. I am using dreamweaver cs5 and I have a basic understanding of php. Thanks again :)